# Lua equivalent of dictionary.get() method?

Tags: lua, lua-table, pico-8

How do I access a dictionary using a parameter?

In python I can do `dictionary.get(param)`
Is there an equivalent to this in lua?

I want to do something like this:

```
function make_object_from_flag(x, y, flag)
 local flag_obj = {
    [1] = make_impassable_object(x, y),
    [2] = make_coin(x,y),
    [4] = make_screen_transition_object(x, y),
 }


 flag_obj.get(flag)
end
```

Comment: `flag_obj[flag]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua only has a single data structure, which is essentially a map (or dictionary) just called "table".

Table indexing in Lua usually works using brackets `[]`, just like python does with arrays.

So basically, as Egor Skriptunoff pointed out in his comment, you want `flag_obj[flag]` to access the value associated with the key `flag` in the table `flag_obj`.

Note though that using bit flags as is done in C is very uncommon and not very performant in Lua, and shouldn't normally be done unless there's some good reason for it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm using flags because I'm coding in pico-8 and thats the built in system. For some reason, flag_obj[flag] still gives me a syntax error though, I'm going to assume it's something relating to pico